# How can I use Realm with newly released versions of Xcode that include new versions of Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, realm

I just updated to Xcode 9 last week, and I've been looking for a way to get around this error:

> Module compiled with Swift 3.1 cannot be imported in Swift 4.0

Each time a new version of Xcode is released that includes a new version of Swift, I have to wait for the RealmSwift project to be updated in order to build and run my project. I am aware that this has to do with Swift's ABI stability, but I also see others who seem to know how to get around this until a compatible version of Realm comes out. Currently, I am running 2.8.0, which was the current release as of last night. My dependency manager of choice is Carthage, but similar questions usually involve CocoaPods, which does not help me very much.

Can anyone offer some clear instructions for unfamiliar ones like me so I can keep working on my project now and when future versions come out? Thank you.

Comment: I thought at WWDC they mentioned that swift 4 was compatible with swift 3. perhaps it is a setting you need to fix in Xcode?

Comment: Are you using CocoaPods, Carthage, downloading a pre-built binary, or building Realm from source?

Comment: Watching the WWDC sessions, I noted that Swift 4 is mostly compatible with Swift 3, and this migration is facilitated by Swift 3.2. For this reason, I wondered if using older versions of RealmSwift with the new Xcode version would be easier than in the past. @Steve

Comment: I am using Carthage, but I would love to find out how to build from source if it is easier. @AustinZ

Comment: Realm-cocoa 2.8.1 should support Xcode 9?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I will update and see if that works.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Update to 2.8.1 did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When using beta versions of Xcode which there are not prebuilt binaries for you need to pass `--no-use-binaries` to `carthage bootstrap` so that Carthage builds all of the dependencies from source.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and all went well until I got this: "warning: argument unused during compilation: '-iapinotes-modules [...]watchos/armv7k'" Should I try to build using "--platform iOS"? Forgive me, I'm new to this.

Comment: i tried this, and carthage built it fine, but xcode still gives the same error. Thoughts to what i'm missing?

Comment: Use `xcode-select` to choose which version of Xcode is used when building on the command line.