# Realm via Carthage for Xcode 9 Beta (9M136h)

Tags: swift, realm, carthage

Does anybody know how to get Realm, via Carthage, for Xcode Beta (9M136h)? If I try grabbing the most recent version (2.8.1) I get a compiler error, stating that the framework was built using Swift 3.1 and thus cannot be used in Swift 4 projects. However the release notes for 2.8.1 states that it's compatible for Xcode 9 Beta. Does the binary for 2.8.1 not work for X9B? Do I have to use a `--no-binary` flag (gross)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44551644/2413303

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use Realm with newly released versions of Xcode that include new versions of Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44550419/how-can-i-use-realm-with-newly-released-versions-of-xcode-that-include-new-versi)